# How to reset a lost root password in SmartOS

Tags: linux, passwords, liveusb

I'm running SmartOS version `joyent_20130405T010449Z` off a bootable USB. Long story short, the root password is lost to the ages.

I tried "root" as the password, no luck. I tried no password, didn't work. I tried the password in platform/root.password on the USB stick, still no luck. The password is something else, and I can't guess it.

I *can* log in by choosing the "Live (noinstall)" option from the grub menu (which uses the `noimport=true` kernel option) and entering "root" as the password. I can then successfully generate a new password hash by running `/usr/lib/cryptpass newpassword`, but after that it's unclear what to do.

I tried following the instructions [located here](https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Changing+Root%27s+Password+in+the+Global+Zone), but they don't seem to apply to me:

When I boot "Live (noinstall)" there is no `/usbkey` mountpoint, and editing `/etc/shadow` has no persistent effects (it resets when I reboot).

I tried editing the entries in `boot/grub/menu.lst` on the usb stick, overriding the `root_shadow=[hash]` kernel option to the output of `/usr/lib/cryptpass newpassword`, but then rebooting and attempting to login with "newpassword" still fails.

As a last resort, I can consider "reinstalling" SmartOS by swapping in a new USB key with a newer version. What will happen to my ZFS pool and my VMs if I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [instructions here](https://docs.smartos.org/changing-the-root-password-in-the-global-zone/) are correct, but they're incomplete in the context of booting in noimport mode. `usbkey` is a filesystem in the "zones" zpool, and when booting in noimport mode it has to be mounted before resetting the password. To mount in noimport mode:

Confirm "zones" zpool exists:

```
$ zpool import
  pool: zones
    id: ##########
 state: ONLINE
 - snip -
```

Import it:

```
$ zpool import zones
```

Confirm zones/usbkey filesystem exists, and is a "legacy" mountpoint (meaning it is mounted with `mount` and not `zfs mount`):

```
$ zfs list
NAME                        USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
- snip -
zones/usbkey                 ###      -   ####  legacy
- snip -
```

Mount it:

```
$ mkdir /usbkey
$ mount -F zfs zones/usbkey /usbkey
```

Then follow the [password reset instructions](https://docs.smartos.org/changing-the-root-password-in-the-global-zone/):

```
$ umount /etc/shadow
$ cp /usbkey/shadow /etc/shadow
$ passwd root
$ cp /etc/shadow /usbkey/shadow
```

And just like that, the password change will be persisted when you reboot normally.